# form error breaking the layout of inline fields

Tags: html, css

I have the below layout, the problem is if one of the field error is not there the layout  is breaking, even one field has `error-wrapper` div the layout should not change min height for the input field stays there and errors will show down without breaking

To see the issue you can comment one div which has `error-wrapper` class

```css
.parent-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

label {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  opacity: 1;
}

.select-container-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 175px;
}

.input-container-wrapper {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}

.error-wrapper {
    align-items: flex-start;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-container">
  <div class="select-container">
    <div>
      <label>Option</label>
      <div class="select-container-wrapper">
        <select>
          <option value="1">Test</option>
        </select>
      </div>
       <div class="error-wrapper">
         Error Occured
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-container">
    <div>
      <label>Number</label>
      <div class="input-container-wrapper">
        <input />
        <svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="css-14z50xn-InventoryWidget" height="1.25rem" width="1.25rem" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M6 19c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h8c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V7H6v12zM19 4h-3.5l-1-1h-5l-1 1H5v2h14V4z"></path>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <!-- If i comment this line the layout breaks -->
       <div class="error-wrapper">
         Error Occured
      </div>
      <!--till here -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a min-height set for any component. And your parent container is set to align center.

Either remove this from .parent-container

```
align-items: center;
```

Or set a minimum height for the wrapping div

```
.select-container > div, .input-container>div{min-height:80px}
```

Then when you remove the error-wrapper, the elements appear unchanged.

Comment: removing align-items: center, thanks @Phaelax for the quick support :)

Comment: I had one doubt regarding on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70063149/event-timeline-with-animation If you can help me on this it will be really helpful, many thanks  